# Splitting a TeamCity server to two servers

Tags: teamcity-9.0

I have a TeamCity system running with various Debug and Release build configurations backed by Templates which match the Debug and Release configurations as follows

- Branch Build Dev Template

  1. Branch 1 Dev Build
  2. Branch 2 Dev Build
- Branch Release Build Template

  1. Branch 1 Release Build
  2. Branch 2 Release Build

I am considering separating the Dev and Release configurations onto two distinct servers to ensure that the Release configurations have a higher level of governance than the Dev configurations while allowing the Dev team to 'play' with the Dev build configurations.

I am not worried about the history on the Dev builds but I want to preserve the history on the Release builds. Therefore I want to copy the Dev build configurations out of the server and import them into a new server specifically for the Dev team.

The server configurations are backed by a Git repo so I have a copy I can work from

Can anyone provide guidance on how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231103/161094) which pointed me in the direction of [Projects Import](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Projects+Import) which looks like a suitable approach for what I am trying to do.

However I want to move certain configurations from a project, not the entire project. If I can find anything further I will post the solution here.

Comment: I didn't find anything else so kudos to @BrokenGlass for his answer on the referenced SO question